# Load back to homepage on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a single page website. If click one of the navbar tabs, lets say 'contact us' the site will scroll down to the contact section. The problem is, if I refresh the site now it will automatically scroll down to the contact section each time. I want the site to scroll to the top of the page every time I refresh. The reason this is happening is because the address bar is changed to **...index.html#contact-area**.

I tried the code below but the site gets caught in an infinite refresh loop.

```
<script>
        window.location.replace("index.html");
</script>
```

I also tried the following but it doesn't work. It starts to scroll up then stops.

```
<script>
        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to attach an event listener to the anchor instead, and instead of changing the page hash, call `scrollIntoView` on the `#contact-area`:

```
anchor.addEventListener('e', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // don't change page hash (unless JS disabled...)
  document.querySelector('#contact-area').scrollIntoView();
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I am currently using an a tag to link to the contact area `<li><a href="#contact-area">Contact</a></li>`. How would I use the event listener instead?

Comment: Also, why did you use the letter 'e' in the event listener code? Shouldn't the event be when the page is refreshed?

Comment: Here is the link to code if you want to check: https://github.com/Haris-Siddiqi/Landing-page  
Here is the link to the page: https://haris-siddiqi.github.io/Landing-page/